# Facebook Send button returns "Invalid Source" error

Tags: facebook, button, send

Recently our Facebook Send button has stopped working.

For some reason it returns "Invalid Source".  It's unclear what this refers to.  Other Facebook code on the site works, and there is no source attribute for the Send button either, making this more confusing!

The actual code returned to the browser from Facebook is this:
for (;;);{"__ar":1,"payload":null,"onload":["SendButtonForm.getInstance(\"uzu1w0_1\").handleError(\"Invalid Source: \");"]}

If anyone could at least tell us what the Invalid Source is returning to, that itself may help!

Thanks,
Mark

edit: looks like it may be this bug
http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/502095993139983?browse=search_500f3189916434754803073

Comment: Show how did you write the send button tag

Comment: Hi Joao, it now seems fine as long as I'm NOT logged in as a Facebook administrator for this account.  As long as I'm logged in as someone else it actually seems to work, so I think it's a safe bet it's the bug I linked.

Comment: This seems to be a facebook bug. try specifying the send button  data-href attribute.

Comment: Late reply but I did try that originally.  However the problem now appears to have been fixed on Facebooks end in sometime in August.  Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

The bug still appears.
When we use `<?php the_permalink() ?>` as data-href tag, "Invalid Source" appears.
BUT if we specify data-href as for example http://www.example.com/ then this FB-recommendation/like works properly. (Of course this is nonsense if we use Wordpress or other PHP pages.)

I verified the code `<?php the_permalink() ?>` generates, and that is a correct HTTP-address, which means this is a Facebook-bug. Mark, please hit your programmers' faces! Thanks! :)